# JRuby with Java7 screws up HTTPS data via proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, proxy, jruby, java-7

I'm trying to use the library restclient (1.6.7) and jrubyopenssl (0.7.3) in our jruby (1.6.8/1.7.2) rails (3.2.11) project. It used to work very nicely with Java 6. Now, as I updated to Java 7 it stopped working. I figured out, that all of these things need to be fulfilled to reproduce the error:

- POST data
- via HTTPS
- across a proxy
- with Java 7

The communication seems to be screwed up, the connected server cannot decode the data in the request (or even the complete request).
I know, it's not easy to reproduce. Maybe someone knows, if the implementation of Java 7 has changed in terms of the HTTPS encryption and how to fix that.

Code:

```
RestClient.proxy = ENV['https_proxy']
RestClient.post 'https://server.com/path', data,  { 'Content-type' => 'application/json' }
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There's one variable in this problem that I'm missing:  What is your proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I had some 'funky' problems like that, and it was from java 6 to 7.

The main difference for me was the """new""" preferred cryptographic mode. Now it is Elliptic curve and AES. But I have a whole stack working well before and the pressure was giant.
I decided to 'downgrade my cryptographic algo' and disable ECC and AES. --> flame war will come and I will not explain why.

So far so good.

And this is a great change, the 'size' of packets change, the handshake change, etc.

Look these:
[1] - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#knownissues
---> Security SESSION...

[2] - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html
--> again same..

I hope these links will put  you onto the right direction. But I think you should disable ecc and aes and use other means (RSA?)